# What is the probability that none of three friends share the same birth-month?

Tags: probability

My question is:

`If birthdays are equally likely in each of 12 months of a year, what is the probability that none of three friends share the same birth-month? Keep 3 decimals.`

This is what I know:
Since 3 of them are born in different months, we have $12C3$ ways. Hence we have $3! \times 12C3$, right?

Then $\frac{3! \times 12C3}{12!}$ would be the answer?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why is $12!$ the denominator? How many different ways are there in all to select birthday months for three people?

Comment: I don't think so. If we assign each of Albert, Bob, and Charlie their birth month, you have $(12)^3$ possibilities overall. Not sure where that $12!$ in your calculations comes from....

Comment: I think it is a lot easier to think of it this way: You choose any month for the first friend, then there is a $11/12$ chance for the second friend not to have his birthday in the same month and then a $10/12$ chance for the third friend not to have his birthday in any of those two months, so the chance of none of them having their birthday in the same month is $11/12*10/12 = 110/144 \approx 0.764$

Answer (score 2):

The numerator $3! \times {}^{12}C_3$ is correct for the number of outcomes where the three birthdays are in different months, but the denominator is incorrect.  You want the number of outcomes with no restriction: each birthday can be in any month. So $12^3$.

Comment: Ah thanks, I realized that

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it is (12 * 11 * 10)/(12 * 12 * 12). My reasoning is below.

Note that there are a total of 12 * 12 * 12 different possible birthday month configurations of the three friends. We can see this by noting that one friend has 12 different possible birthday months, with each of those possible birthday months possibly going with one of the 12 different possible birthday months of the second friend, so considering just those two friends we have 12 * 12 different configurations of their birthday months. Then, with each of these possibilities possibly going with the 12 different possible birthday months of the third friend, we have a total of 12 * 12 * 12 configurations of the three friends' birthday months.

Then, consider one of the possible birthday months for friend 1. Note then that there are 11 different possible birthday months where friend 2 does not share the same birthday as friend 1. Then, note that with each of the 11 possible months where friend 2 does not share a birthday with the chosen birthday month of friend 1, we have 10 different possible birthday months where friend 3 does not share the same birthday with friend 2 or friend 3 (friend 1 takes up a birthday month, and friend 2 takes up another birthday month in one of the 11 cases, so friend 3 is only left with 10 other possible different birthday months for each of the 11 cases considered). So, for every possible birthday month of friend 1, we have that there are 11 * 10 different ways the three friends do not share a birthday. So, with friend 1 having 12 possible birthday months, we have that there are a total of 12 * 11 * 10 different ways that none of the three friends do not share a birthday.

So, we then have that the probability that none of the friends share a birthday month is by definition

(Number of ways they do not share a birthday months)/(Total number of possible configurations of the birthday months of the three friends)

which is equal to

(12 * 11 * 10)/(12 * 12 * 12)

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{11\times10}{12^2}$ seems to be a simpler approach.